# Retrieve Content of Span Using Google Script into Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spotify

Trying to scrape the monthly listener count(among other things) of a friend on Spotify and import it into a Google sheet so he can quickly reference that data and monitor his growth. What I'm getting isn't matching what's on the website.

I attempted to use the IMPORTXML function and it returns nothing.

`=IMPORTXML("https://open.spotify.com/artist/1AdskP8cgmAIqfRQkDTJ36", "//span[contains(@class, 'faffb409617fd7cf35017fde898cf860-scss')]")`

Then I did this. Strangely, this does return a number but it doesn't match what is on the website. This returns 14,421 even though his listener count is 32,214 at the time of writing this:

`=IMPORTXML("https://open.spotify.com/artist/1AdskP8cgmAIqfRQkDTJ36", "//h3")`

Then I attempted to do it in an apps script but when I run the following code to see what's being returned, the monthly listeners count that it returns in logs is different from what's on the website similar to above. Why is that? Any ideas on how to get the exact number a user sees when they visit: https://open.spotify.com/artist/1AdskP8cgmAIqfRQkDTJ36

```
function returnData() {
var url = "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1AdskP8cgmAIqfRQkDTJ36";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I get 32,214 http://prntscr.com/vxr3j0.

Comment: That's very odd. I wonder why you're getting a different number from me? https://prnt.sc/vxs64d

Comment: Can you break the formula or copy it to a different cell to see if it refreshes

Comment: Tried adding it to another sheet. Tried calling the URL from a different cell... no dice. The only thing I can think of is that it is cached related but I'm at a total loss here. Is there a better way to do this than the ImportXML function?